# Update SQL Server Database from another db

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I have a test and production environment using SQL Server 2008 R2. I want to update some columns from my test environment to my prod environment. My query makes sense to me but it keeps erroring. Any advice on how to proceed with this is greatly appreciated.

```
use [NGProd]

update nxmd_practice_web_text
set nxmd_practice_web_text.item_value = TST.item_value
from [TestSQL1].[NGTest].[dbo].[nxmd_practice_web_text] TST
where TST.nx_modified_by = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000002692'
  and nxmd_practice_web_text.item_id = 4100
  and nxmd_practice_web_text.nx_practice_id = TST.nx_practice_id
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>
> Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

The `item_value` column is `ntext` but I am not comparing it. I am setting it so this error is really confusing to me.

I understand that the `ntext` data type is deprecated, but there is nothing I can do about it. This is a paid for product with millions of rows of data across thousands of tables. I can not modify this row type without it be converted back in future updates (which post semi annually).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). Get rid of the deprecated `ntext` and most likely your problem will just vanish ....

Comment: I understand that but there is nothing I can do about it. This is a paid for product with millions of rows of data across thousands of tables. I can not modify this row type without it be converted back in future updates (which post semi annually) As a result marc_s I need a way for this to work the way the db is.

Comment: Just to be clear, are both item_values ntext on both tables?

Comment: Check to make sure that there is not an `UPDATE TRIGGER` on table `nxmd_practice_web_text`, which might be trying to compare old/new values of a field that is `text/ntext`.

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath Yes both are ntext on both tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying to recreate your error using a Sql 2008 and a Sql 2000 server, I could only get a similar error when I changed the nx_modified_by to ntext or practice_id to ntext.
The Sql Server 2008 Error Message was:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   The data types ntext and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

I'm guessing the nx_modified_by is also ntext (instead of unique_identifier), but included a commented out line in case it is the nx_practice_id.

Try This:

```
use [NGProd]
go
update prod 
  set prod.item_value = tst.item_value 
  from NGProd.[dbo].[nxmd_practice_web_text] as prod
    inner join [TestSQL1].[NGTest].[dbo].[nxmd_practice_web_text] as tst
      on prod.nx_practice_id = tst.nx_practice_id
      /*
        on cast(prod.nx_practice_id as varchar(8000)) 
         = cast(prod.nx_practice_id as varchar(8000)) 
         --*/
  where prod.item_id = 4100
    and cast(tst.nx_modified_by as varchar(36)) 
      = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000002692'
    --and tst.nx_modified_by = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000002692'
```

Also, make sure you have In Process enabled on the Linked Server Properties

[Technet - Linked Server Properties - Allow inprocess](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188095%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> **Allow inprocess**
>
> > SQL Server allows the provider to be instantiated as an in-process server. When this option is not set, the default behavior is to instantiate the provider outside the SQL Server process. Instantiating the provider outside the SQL Server process protects the SQL Server process from errors in the provider. When the provider is instantiated outside the SQL Server process, updates or inserts referencing long columns **(text, ntext, or image)** are not allowed.

Comment: heh you posted nearly an identical query just a few seconds before me. :)

Comment: Nice! I like my formatting better, but you have a better intro.

Comment: I wrote mine in notepad. :D

Comment: I wrote mine in notepad++ :P

Comment: I've never had any problems using the update format in the original question.

Comment: @SqlZim This also gives an error :/

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

I removed the semicolon and it cleared the where error but gave me my original error again

Comment: @Jordan Sorry about that extra semicolon yesterday. I think this updated answer should have what you need.

Comment: @SqlZim nice job on this answer!  @Jordan, so which one fixed your problem?  Was `nx_modified_by` really `ntext` data type or was it the linked server `Allow inprocess` setting?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues going on there. When issuing an update and getting the values from a joined query you need to update the alias. Otherwise you can get some funky results. You could change your update to something more like this.

```
update wt
set item_value = cast(TST.item_value as varchar(max))
from [TestSQL1].[NGTest].[dbo].[nxmd_practice_web_text] TST
join nxmd_practice_web_text wt on wt.nx_practice_id = TST.nx_practice_id
where TST.nx_modified_by = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000002692'
  and wt.item_id = 4100
```

Comment: I've never had any problems using the update format in the original question.

Comment: @Sean Lange When I use yours it gives the exact same error as before :/

Comment: Without the ddl for these two tables there is little else we can do. Can you create a sqlfiddle with the two tables?